# How can I dynamically create a tree using Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I'm going to create a tree using python dict without knowing the exact number of levels and nodes before doing it.

For example I'm gonna loop many items with 3 attributes: size, color, and weight. In each loop I do the following things

```
item_data = {}
for item in items:
    size, color, weight = item.get_attr()
    if size not in item_data:
        item_data[size] = {}
    if color not in item_data[size]:
        item_data[size][color] = {}
    if weight not in item_data[size][color]:
        item_data[size][color][weight] = []
    # Do something to the tree...
```

Finally I get a dict like this

```
item_data == {'L':{
                  'red':{45:[...], 
                         50:[...]}, 
                  'green':{
                         40:[...]}}, 
              'XL':{...}}
```

But this is not flexible. For example if I want to add another attribute like 'price'? I have to know it and add one more if in the codes above.

I'm thinking about doing it in the following way, but don't know how to do it in few lines

```
attrs = [item.get_attr()]
for attr in attrs:
    # Create the tree here..
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [networkx](http://networkx.github.io) is relevant here. Otherwise, here is a basic version extending your idea of using `attr` loop (code not tested).

```
for item in items:
    tree = item_data
    for i,attr in enumerate(item.get_attr()):
        if attr not in tree.keys():
            if i<len(item.get_attr())-1:
                tree[attr] = {}
            else:
                tree[attr] = []
        else:
            tree = tree[attr]
    # do something to the tree
```

Comment: It works! only a minor difference is that the last else is not needed because the tree node always need to go to the next level. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry. I wrote this code. http://ideone.com/7JvBub It doesnt work. It says `AttributeError: Item instance has no attribute 'get_attr'` Which type of objects will work with `get_attr`?

Comment: I thought the `get_attr` was a user defined function. If you intend to use the built in `getattr` function, then the syntax is `getattr(obj)`.